# Summation problem (probability)

Tags: probability, summation, arithmetic

I have the equation $$\Pr(X\le6)=\sum_{x=6}^{∞}\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{x}}{x!}\right).$$

And it is not equating to when I sum each term manually.

Plugging this into my calculator I get 0.348994, however when I sum each term (like below) I get 0.790805 which seems more likely.

$$\Pr(X\le6)=\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3)+\Pr(X=4)+\Pr(X=5)+\Pr(X=6)\\=\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{0}}{0!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{1}}{1!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{2}}{2!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{3}}{3!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{4}}{4!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{5}}{5!}\right)+\left({e^{-4.8}}\cdot\frac{4.8^{6}}{6!}\right)$$
$$=0.00823+0.39503+0.94807+0.151691+0.182029+0.174748+0.139798$$
$$=0.790805$$

I have been through my working several times now and don't know where I went wrong...

Comment: The desired probability is in fact approximately $0.790805$ as you wrote.  Its precise value is $$\frac{7507109}{78125} e^{-24/5}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum goes from $x=0$ to $6$, not $6$ to $\infty$.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the use of $x$ both as the random variable and the summation variable is the cause of the confusion here. OP should change $\sum\limits_{x=6}^{\infty}$ to $\sum\limits_{k=6}^{\infty}$. And it is not entirely clear if both occurrences of $x$ **in the term itself** should be replaced by $k$.

Comment: @barakmanos The random variable is $X$, the values are denoted by $x$.  I see no advantage in changing $x$ to $k$.  This has nothing to do with the confusion.

Comment: Not your confusion perhaps, but most like (so I believe) OP's confusion.